# Angular Directives - How to set attributes to innerHML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-directive

how to set attributes to the inner HTML

tpl.html

```
<div class="my-templeate"></div>
```

HTML

```
<template></template>
```

directive

```
app.directive('template', ['$compile', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            templateUrl: './tpl.html',
            link: function($scope, $elm, $attr) {

                var elm =$elm[0].innerHTML;

                elm.attr('id', "someId");
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Here I want to set attributes to the innerHtml `<div class="my-templeate"></div>` that is appended to the `<template></template>` element.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have this massive and powerful framework at your disposal, you may as well make some use of it.  Set data on scope and let the template read it, instead of bypassing Angular to edit the DOM on your own.  The template:

```
<div class="my-template" id="{{someId}}"></div>
```

The directive:

```
app.directive('template', ['$compile', function($compile) { // $compile is unnecessary here unless you're using it for something else in this directive
    return {
        templateUrl: './tpl.html',
        link: function($scope, $elm, $attr) {
            $scope.someId = "whatever";
        }
    };
}]);
```

In general, if you're manipulating the DOM directly when using Angular, you're probably doing things either the hard way or the completely wrong way.

Comment: thanks, I already knew this method. I wanted to know. how to work that way too.

Comment: OK.   My answer then is "don't do that." It's unnecessary extra work and prone to causing difficult-to-track-down bugs (it's easy to overwrite angular bindings, etc.)

Comment: I was trying not to make it work. I just wanted to know how to make that work. thanks for the tip